# How to combine 2 exposed filters (String and Taxonomy field)

Tags: 7, views

I need to create a View with a search box for my content type; the search string has to match both title OR a CCK taxonomy field. Is there a Views module that permits to do it? I've tried http://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate but it only works with 2 string fields.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Populate module doesn't work with taxonomy filter. I can give you advice to do it in one of views_hooks. You can add custom "where" condition to your query using value of exposed filter. (http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/7)

Answer (score 3):

Yes,by default drupal handled this.
in `Filter criteria` in your views  click and hold `arrow sign` beside `add`.open   menu with `And/Or, Rearrange`.In this section(`Rearrange filter criteria`) you can determine gorup for your filter and  criteria between your filters.

Comment: Cool, didn't know it, thanks! But i still have a problem ... if i expose a filter on title, i need to add as OR condition another field (a taxonomy term); if i do this it does not work. Is it possible to use the exposed filter and make the OR from this and another field?

Comment: yes,it is . you can gorup up them, you can use OR condition in a group and another group use AND  and between gorups use AND or OR .