# Show search results in block

Tags: 7, blocks, search

When you click on a search result, you navigate to that node or user. I would like to show the search results in a block when a user navigates to one of the search results, so the other results are always quickly available. Any idea if this is possible?

I was thinking... Make search result variable ($search_results) global, and show this in a php block. But maybe there are better ways to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Override [search-result.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7) with below code

```
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url . '?search_keyword=' . arg(2); ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($info): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

Then create a view that displays search results using views module and add a contextual filter saying search term, which is returned using PHP Code.

You can read the value in views contextual filter using `$_GET['search_keyword']` and return the same.

Once view block is built, enable it in the pages you want !

Comment: Yes, I see, the basic idea looks great. But how do you create a view that displays the search results in Drupal 7?

Comment: The simplest answer I know to that question is to use Search API + Search API Database instead of core search.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment I don't know any contrib module that fit this use-case but I know a module that may interest you in some way.

The module is the [Search API Page Block](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_page_block). Here goes a summary of the module description:

> This module exposes Search API Pages as blocks and uses the node's
>   title as keywords. This allows you to use your existing search results
>   page to direct users to related content.
>
> Currently, this module is only useful when placing search result
>   blocks on node pages, since it currently only uses $node->title as the
>   search keywords. Future development can lead to other uses, including
>   using Taxonomy terms, Context module, or custom fields to set the
>   keywords.

To achieve your goal I think you will need to implement a cutom module that stores the result of the user's search and uses the result list as the content of a block implemented by your custom module.

Maybe you can try another approach by using the [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module with exposed filters then use the [Views filters populate](https://drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) to merge them in a single text field and using a block to show the view result. This approach will let you easily store the keyword in a variable using the [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in conjunction with the [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) and so on.

Here goes a question about the Views Filter Populate that may be useful:

[How to combine 2 exposed filters (String and Taxonomy field)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42048/how-to-combine-2-exposed-filters-string-and-taxonomy-field)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Anil's answer:

Use Page Manager (part of Chaos Tools) to collect the arguments from the URL and Panels to render the page with the search results visible.

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing on Anil's search result template with an alternative to the views search block, it's not too bad to implement a block displaying search results in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
    $blocks['search-results'] = array(
        'info' => t('Search Results'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
    );

    return $blocks;
}

function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'search-results':
            if (array_key_exists('search_keyword', $_GET)) {
                $element = PagerDefault::$maxElement;
                $block['subject'] = NULL; // search data renders with a header
                $block['content']['results'] = search_data(check_plain($_GET['search_keyword']), 'node');
                $block['content']['pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager', '#element' => $element);
            }
            break;
    }

    return $block;
}
```

Granted the results didn't seem to know which pager element to render so I declared it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

[search_api_page_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page_block)

> The Search API Page module already exposes the search forms as block.
>   This takes that functionality one step further. This module exposes
>   Search API Pages as blocks and uses the node's title as keywords. This
>   allows you to use your existing search results page to direct users to
>   related content.